# Hyperbolic Metric on a Riemann Surface

Tags: riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, moduli-space, teichmueller-theory

From uniformization theorem, it is known that every conformal class of metrics on a Riemann surface contains a unique hyperbolic metric. For a genus-$g$ Riemann surface with $n$ punctures, the punctures correspond to fixed points of the parabolic elements of the associated Fuchsian group. The question is that: *what is the explicit local expression of this unique hyperbolic metric for such a surface around a puncture, associated with the fixed point $x$ of a parabolic element?* A good reference is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean to start from $X \cong \Gamma/\mathbb{H}$ with $\Gamma \subset \text{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, set  $E = \Gamma \cap \left(\begin{smallmatrix}1 & * \\0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and take the points of $X$ fixed by $E$ ? Then the hyperbolic metric on $\mathbb{H}$ is $\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2}$ so it should be the same as finding a covering $\mathbb{H} \to X$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the hyperbolic plane model $\mathbb{H}$, set the fixed point of the parabolic element at $\infty$, and choose the parabolic element to be $\gamma(z)=z+1$.
We know that the infinitesimal hyperbolic metric for $\mathbb{H}$ is given by $|ds|=\frac{|d\xi|}{\operatorname{Im}(\xi)}$, where $\operatorname{Im}(\xi)$ denotes the imaginary part of $\xi \in \mathbb{H}$ and $|d\xi|$ is the Euclidean infinitesimal element of length.
There is a holomorphic map $\phi: \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{C} \backslash\{0\}$ given by $\xi \mapsto e^{2\pi i \xi}$.
If we restrict to the fundamental domain of $\langle \gamma \rangle$ given by $F:=\{ \xi \in \mathbb{H} : 0<\operatorname{Re}(\xi) <1 \}$, then $\phi(F)=\mathbb{D}\backslash\{ 0\}$ biholomorphically.
Let $\psi:=(\phi|_{F})^{-1} : \mathbb{D}\backslash\{ 0\} \to F \subset \mathbb{H}$. This map is $z \mapsto \xi=\frac{\log(z)}{2\pi i}$.
We can compute the hyperbolic metric in $\mathbb{D}\backslash\{ 0\}$ by pulling back the metric in $F \subset \mathbb{H}$ via $\psi$.

First, note that

$$\frac{\log(z)}{2\pi i}=\frac{\log|z|}{2\pi i} + \frac{1}{2\pi}\arg(z).$$

So that $\operatorname{Im}(\psi(z))=-\frac{\log|z|}{2\pi}$.

Moreover, $\psi'(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i z}$.

If we compute the pullback mentioned above, we get the local expression of the hyperbolic metric around a cusp, as we desired.

$$|dr|=\psi^*|ds|=\psi^*\frac{|d\xi|}{|\operatorname{Im}(\xi)|}=\frac{|\psi'(z)||dz|}{|\operatorname{Im}(\psi(z))|}=\frac{1}{2\pi|z|}\frac{2\pi}{\log|z|}=\frac{1}{|z|\log|z|}.$$

Depending on the kind of computations you want to do, there might be other convenient coordinates to describe this metric. 
Another example are horocyclic coordinates.

[image]

Consider again the hyperbolic plane model, and pick a horocycle centered at some point $p_0$ of the ideal boundary $\mathbb{R} \cup \infty$. In figure A, we are choosing $p_0=0$ and the horocycle is drawn in red, and parametrized arc length via $h(t)$, with the convention that $p_0$ lies on the left-hand-side of $h$. For an arbitrary point $p$ (blue in figure A), consider the unique geodesic intersecting $h$ orthogonally and going through $p$ (the geodesic is green in figure A). We define two coordinates: 
1. Denote $\rho$ the distance from $h$ to $p$ along this geodesic, with the convention of $\rho$ being positive if it lies on the right-hand-side of $h$. 
2. Let $h(t)$ be the intersection point of $h$ with the green geodesic, and let the second coordinate be $t$.

The coordinates $(\rho,t)$ for a fixed horocycle with center in the cusp are called the horocyclic coordinates.
In figure B we represent these coordinates choosing the cusp to be at $\infty$ and thus $p_0=\infty$, as we did in the beginning of this post. Now horocycles look like horizontal lines. We choose the specific horocycle at height $y=1$ (in red), with the parametrization $h(t)=t+i$, and we define $\rho$ and $t$ as before.
With this specific choice of horocycle, the metric tensor is

$$dr^2=d\rho^2 + e^{2\rho} dt^2$$

and this gives another expression for the local metric around a cusp.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. Can you please refer to a reference on this topic where I can find more details about hyperbolic structure on a Riemann surface?

Comment: Chapters 1, 2 and 3 in John Hubbard's book "Teichmüller Theory and Applications to Geometry, Topology, and Dynamics, volume 1". I would also recommend the first chapters in "Geometry and Spectra of Compact Riemann Surfaces" by Peter Buser. He gives a detailed description of horocyclic coordinates.