# the universal covering space of the connected sum of $m$ torus

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I want to prove that $\mathbb R^2$ is the universal covering space of the connected sum of $m$ torus $mT=T\sharp T\sharp ...\sharp T$.

I try to argue as follows: first, prove that $\mathbb R^2$ is the universal covering space of the double torus $2T=T\sharp T$; then prove that $mT$ is the covering space of $(m-1)T$. At last, by the universal property of universal covering space and induction, we have $\mathbb R^2$ is the universal covering space of the connected sum of $m$ torus $mT=T\sharp T\sharp ...\sharp T$.

But how to prove the above two statement (the inductive hypothesis)? It seems that we can't find an explicit expression of the covering projection.

Comment: The universal covering space for $T\#T$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ but its construction involves the Poincaré disk and hyperbolic geometry. This part of the argument is not trivial, see for example the last section of Lee - Introduction to Topological Manifolds Chapter 12.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4296146/what-is-the-universal-covering-of-surface-with-genus-2/4296457#4296457'

Comment: In general, $mT$ doesn't cover $(m-1)T$.  To see this, recall that if a space finitely $X$ covers a space $Y$ and they both have Euler characteristics, then $\chi(X)/\chi(Y)$ is a positive integer (the number of sheets).  Because $mT$ and $(m-1)T$ are both compact, and possible covering would have finitely many sheets, so this applies.  But $\chi(mT) = 2-2m$, and so$(1-m)/(2-m)$ must be a positive integer.  This implies $m=3$.  On the other hand, something similar to what you're trying will work:  for every $m\geq 2$, $mT$ does cover $2T$.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, we can build on @JasonDeVito's argument to get an answer: the universal covering space of $mT$ must be a simply-connected surface, so it must be either $\Bbb{R}^2$ or $S^2$, but Jason's observations about Euler characteristics imply that it cannot be $S^2$, so it must be $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @Rob: I was suggesting a rather easier approach, since I find that fact that the only simply connected surfaces are $S^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ to be a hard theorem.  Here's the key:  If $X$ covers $Y$, then $X$ and $Y$ have the same universal cover.  Then, if the OP can prove that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the universal cover of $2T$, it follows from my other comment that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the universal cover of $mT$ for all $m\geq 2$.  Lee Mosher gives an argument that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the universal cover of $2T$ here:https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131863/universal-covering-of-compact-surfaces.